# HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-rs

I have created a sample web service to make a post call.

I am using Jersey JAX-RS, and Maven.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>provider-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.is.ws.provider.rest.ProviderAggregateApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
         </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>provider-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

POM.XML

```
<!-- Jersey jars -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

Method call:

```
@POST
@Path(RESOURCE_PATH)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getPCP(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

Raw request:

```
 POST http://localhost:9080/sep/pas/getPCP HTTP/1.1
 Connection: close
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Length: 69
 Host: localhost:9080
 User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

  {
    "patientID": "1234567890",
    "patientIDType": "XYZ"
  }
```

I have referred to following article

[REST Webservice returning 415 - Unsupported Media Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932080/rest-webservice-returning-415-unsupported-media-type)

But still i'm having issue.

Comment: The exception is usually thrown if the container receiving the request can not map the request to a respective method. Therefore, have you defined a `@Path` at class-level? What is `RESOURCE_PATH`? is it `/sep/pas/getPCP`? Furthermore, you declared a JSON media-type via `@Consumes` but did not provide any parameter that can take this sent JSON body (Object, String, POJO, ...)

Comment: @RomanVottner `resource_path` works fine. I don't think there is any issue with that, because I have used same `resource_path` for `@Get` and it worked. With `@Consumes` I removed it before method and I'm returning a string in my method. Still I get 415

Comment: Do you also get a 415 if you change for test-purposes your `@Consumes` declaration to `plain/text`? If not, then the automarshalling from JSON might fail.

Comment: I edited my method call, there is no `@consumes`. I am doing a simple post call and expecting a string as output.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a `String` parameter for `getPCP`? Also, try to change the content-type of the request to `plain/text`

Comment: I played a bit with the jar files what i included in the pom.xml, at the end I used following jars `jersey-core` , `jersey-bundle`, 'jersey-json` and finally it worked :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution :) But please be so kind and create an answer where you post your solution and mark it as accepted so that other people having the same issues might avoid posting the same issue again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all my dependency code in pom.xml and added following code which has jersey-core, jersey-bundle, jersey-json

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it could be you forgot a default no-parameters constructor for your Patient class.

In detail, I faced the same `415` http error when sending objects, serialized into JSON, via PUT/PUSH requests to my JAX-rs services, in other words my server was not able to de-serialize the objects from JSON.
In my case, the server was able to serialize successfully the same objects in JSON when sending them into its responses.

As mentioned in the other responses I have correctly set the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers to `application/json`, but it doesn't suffice.

**Solution**

I simply forgot a default constructor with no parameters for my DTO objects. Yes this is the same reasoning behind @Entity objects, you need a constructor with no parameters for the ORM to instatiate objects and populate the fields later.

Adding the constructor with no parameters to my DTO objects solved my issue.
Here an example that resembles my code:

**Wrong**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class NumberDTO {
    public NumberDTO(Number number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    private Number number;

    public Number getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Number number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

**Right**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class NumberDTO {

    public NumberDTO() {
    }

    public NumberDTO(Number number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    private Number number;

    public Number getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Number number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

I lost hours, I hope this'll save yours ;-)