# PUT - Sending JSON - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: json, spring, rest, jersey

I have a REST service in **Jersey** , which I am implementing using **Postman**

I get the following error in postman :

**415 Unsupported Media Type**

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692221/jersey-415-unsupported-media-type) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932080/rest-webservice-returning-415-unsupported-media-type) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423776/post-to-jersey-rest-service-getting-error-415-unsupported-media-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773846/error-415-unsupported-media-type-post-not-reaching-rest-if-json-but-it-does-if) . Nothing Works.

I am sending JSON and the **request method is PUT**

I am trying to update a resource through a method in a service , called

updateMessage.

My Code :

```
package org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes.jersey_quickstart_webapp.resources;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes.jersey_quickstart_webapp.model.Message;
import org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes.jersey_quickstart_webapp.service.MessageService;


@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {
    
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Message> getMessages()
    {
        return messageService.getAllMessages();
    }
    
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message addMessage(Message message)
    {
         return messageService.add(message);
    }
    
    @PUT
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    
    
    public Message updateMessage(@PathParam("messageId")long id,Message message)
    {
        message.setId(id);
        return messageService.updateMessage(message);
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message getMessage(@PathParam("messageId")long id)
    {
        return messageService.getMessage(id);
        //return "Got Path Param" + messageId;
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////My Service///////////////////////////////

```
package org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes.jersey_quickstart_webapp.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes.jersey_quickstart_webapp.database.DatabaseClass;
import org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes.jersey_quickstart_webapp.model.Message;

public class MessageService {
    
    private Map<Long, Message> messages = DatabaseClass.getMessages();

     public MessageService() {
        messages.put(1l, new Message(1, "Hello World", "Nishil"));
        messages.put(2l, new Message(2, "Hello Jersey", "Nishil"));
    }
    
    
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public List<Message> getAllMessages()
    {
        
        messages.values();
        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
        
    }
    public Message getMessage(long id)
    {
        return messages.get(id);
    }
    
    public Message add(Message message)
    {
        message.setId(messages.size()+1);
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
    }
    
    public Message updateMessage(Message message)
    {
        if(message.getId()<=0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
        
    }

public Message removeMessage(long id)
{
    return messages.remove(id);
}
}
```

Comment: So everything else is working but the `PUT`?

Comment: Yes, everything else is working

Comment: I also tried changing @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  to  @Produces("application/json")

Comment: Did you set the `Content-Type` header in postman?

Comment: This is the JSON I am sending.: {
    "author": "Nishil",
    "created": "2016-10-14T10:44:37.29",
    "message": "Hello World!!!"
  "content-type" : "application/json"
}

Comment: I am updating the resource 'messages'

Comment: Put the content type in the header not the body

Comment: Yes. Error solved. thanks. Please post an answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type: application/json` header in Postman. I believe it just defaults to `text/plain` if you don't set it, hence the "unsupported media type".