# Ajax POST to Rest API Spring boot

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, rest, post

I'm trying to post a form from my HTML to my rest service. I'm getting an error that i can't manage to overcome...

Rest service :

The json is constructed correctly. I just don't understand why the media type isn't right... 
the error (just happening in chrome console, server is fine) :

Class :

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932080/rest-webservice-returning-415-unsupported-media-type

Comment: I edited my code and tried to add the request header but still not working. Also i have default constructor in location class...

Comment: Provide some code