# angular 5 Getting an error on POST request. Sending header param not works

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http

I am trying to send a POST request like :

```
public getAppData(countryPath) : Observable<any> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.retailApi, JSON.stringify(this.postParam), {headers: options } );
}
```

But I am getting an error as:

[image: Option not works]

What is wrong here? Can anyone help me to figure it out?

after I tried with another option, I got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

please import `HttpClient` and `HttpHeaders` like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and inject to your class:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
```

and your method like this:

```
 public getAppData(countryPath):Observable<any>{
      let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post(this.retailApi, JSON.stringify(this.postParam), { headers: headers });
    }
```

Comment: works,but getting this error : `POST http://localhost:9001/retail/api/load 415 ()` - any help?

Comment: But I still see as `Content-Type: text/plain` in my `request Headers` - any issue?

Comment: what is your api programming language

Comment: Java is my api programming language

Comment: this answer code work correctly, you need set your `api` accept content to `json`

Comment: this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932080/rest-webservice-returning-415-unsupported-media-type?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa